# Copying the value of one data Table to another data Table in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually, i have two data tables. Here is the code for reference. Actually **Relationship** holds the sub string values(Code not mentioned here). So i am splitting the data's to store in two table's based on the condition.

```
 if (child.Relationship.Contains("P"))
{
   var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
   newRow["EmployeeNo"] = child.EmployeeNo;
   newRow["FirstName"] = child.FirstName;
   newRow["MiddleName"] = child.MiddleName;
   newRow["LastName"] = child.LastName;
   newRow["FullName"] = child.FullName;
   newRow["MemberIc"] = child.MemberIc;
   dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
   }
else
   {
     var newRow1 = dataTable1.NewRow();
     newRow1["EmployeeNo"] = child.EmployeeNo;
     newRow1["FirstName"] = child.FirstName;
     newRow1["MiddleName"] = child.MiddleName;
     newRow1["LastName"] = child.LastName;
     newRow1["FullName"] = child.FullName;     
     newRow1["MemberIC"] = child.MemberIC;         
     dataTable1.Rows.Add(newRow1);
     }
```

So, whenever the MemberIc in the second data table is empty. I need to copy the MemberIc from first data table(only if EmployeeNo Matches) based on the **EmployeeNo**. 
How can i copy the value ? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You first need to get the employeeId from the first table for the matching employeeid and store it in some variable. Then then when you are inserting the row you use this variable to set the EmployeeId column value.

Comment: can i have a sample @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
var rows = datatable.Select("EmployeeNo = " + child.EmployeeNo);

var memberIC = 0;
if(rows.length > 0)
{
    memberIC = rows[0].Field<int>("memberIC");
}

if (child.Relationship.Contains("P"))
{
   var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
   newRow["EmployeeNo"] = child.EmployeeNo;
   newRow["FirstName"] = child.FirstName;
   newRow["MiddleName"] = child.MiddleName;
   newRow["LastName"] = child.LastName;
   newRow["FullName"] = child.FullName;
   newRow["MemberIc"] = child.MemberIc;
   dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
else
{
    var newRow1 = dataTable1.NewRow();
    newRow1["EmployeeNo"] = child.EmployeeNo;
    newRow1["FirstName"] = child.FirstName;
    newRow1["MiddleName"] = child.MiddleName;
    newRow1["LastName"] = child.LastName;
    newRow1["FullName"] = child.FullName;     
    newRow1["MemberIC"] = child.MemberIC == 0 ? memberIC : child.MemberIC;         
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(newRow1);
}
```

This has nothing to do with C#, ADO.NET or datatable. This is a simple logic of what to check and where to check.